# Why does this simple Left Join return data from unmatched rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Please see the simple http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e853f/1 for this problem  in operation.

I refer to MySQL ver 5.6.12-log

As I understand it, a left join returns NULL for columns in the rightmost dataset where the key in the left dataset does not exist in the right dataset.

However, I am getting data returned from the right hand side even where the left hand key does not exist in the right.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

The SQLfiddle creates:

- A table with 6 rows, each containing just an integer ID
- A second table with 3 rows containing some of those integer IDs plus two
  more INT fields
- A view based upon that second table that returns 3 rows containing the integer ID plus a textual field, derived from the two other INT fields

*(Obviously, the 3 IDs in the view correspond to some of the IDs in the 6 row table.)*

The SQL 
SELECT * FROM  LEFT JOIN  ON table_ID = view_ID;
returns 6 rows as expected but **all** of them have data in the textual field instead of the 3 unmatched ones being NULL

**BUT**

If the method used in the view to derive the textual column is slightly altered, then the Left Join SQL gives the correct result.
*(You can show this by selectively commenting out one or other of the two methods in sql fiddle)*

But surely doesn't the optimiser evaluate the view first, so it shouldn't matter how the data is created, just what it contains?

*(This s a much simplified version of an earlier question of mine that I admit was rather too complicated to illicit sensible answers)*

It has been suggested (Jeroen Mostert)that I show data and expected results. Here it is:

**Table person**

```
personID
--------
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
```

**View payment_state**

```
payment_personID  |   state
----------------------------
       1          |   'equal'
       2          |   'under'
       3          |   'over'
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM  person 
LEFT JOIN   payment_state 
ON personID = payment_personID;
```

**Expected result**

```
personID | payment_personID  |state
-------------------------------------
    1    |      1            | 'equal'
    2    |      2            | 'under'
    3    |      3            | 'over'
    4    |     NULL          |  NULL
    5    |     NULL          |  NULL
    6    |     NULL          |  NULL
```

**Actual result**

```
personID | payment_personID  |state
-------------------------------------
    1    |      1            | 'equal'
    2    |      2            | 'under'
    3    |      3            | 'over'
    4    |     NULL          | 'equal'
    5    |     NULL          | 'equal'
    6    |     NULL          | 'equal'
```

Comment: If you switch the RDBMS used to "SQL Server 2017" or "PostgreSQL" and replace `IFNULL` with `COALESCE` (to make the syntax work) you will get exactly the results you expect. (Which is, I believe, also the result you should get as far as ANSI SQL is concerned, but don't quote me on that). This looks like a MySQL oddity.

Comment: Add the sample data and the current result and the expected result here. Formatted text, please.

Comment: @jarlh 6  It is all very clear in the SQL fiddle. I have deliberately not reproduced it here to make my question succinct and clear

Comment: @user2834566: from at least one comment and at least one answer that don't seem to understand the issue at hand, consider the possibility that it's still not clear enough. You may wish to elaborate with a "I do this, I got this, I expected this" with no requirement of the reader to press buttons.

Comment: "left join returns NULL for columns in the rightmost dataset where the key in the left dataset does not exist in the right dataset" That is very poorly phrased & if it were clear it would be wrong because that only applies to certain joins involving keys, but the general definition does not involve keys. Left join on returns inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Unmatched rows are ones that are not part of a row in the inner join on result. Ones that could not make the ON condition true with any row from the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing algorithm of your view causes this result. For default, MySQL usually  chooses MERGE, because it is more efficient. If you create a view with "TEMPTABLE" algorithm you will be able to see NULL for the unmatched rows.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx

```
CREATE ALGORITHM =  TEMPTABLE VIEW  payment_state AS (
SELECT
   payment_personID,
 CASE 
   WHEN IFNULL(paid,0) < IFNULL(due,0) AND due <> 0 THEN 'under' 
   WHEN IFNULL(paid,0) > IFNULL(due,0) THEN 'over' 
   WHEN IFNULL(paid,0) = IFNULL(due,0) THEN 'equal' 
   END AS state 
FROM payments);
```

Comment: That's amazing. It's just like the view definition for additional columns was copied instead of actual results. The `ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE` parts works like an added `.ToList()` in C#, materializing data here and now before `JOIN`ing it.

You learn something new every day :)

Comment: Seems like a good illustration of the MySQL philosophy: make it fast, then give the user options to make it correct (if they insist).

Comment: That really is something I would not have expected! I had read the documentation on algorithms here (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-views-mysql.aspx) but nowhere did it say 'Oh by the way, merge gives the wrong result'. I still don't quite follow the logic though. If merge combines the queries then somewhere it must be evaluating IFNULL(paid,0) = IFNULL(due,0) to get 'equal' for the unmatched keys. But even if it does this after the join, although the unmatched 'paid' columns will be null, none of the 'due' ones are so I don't quite see how it evaluates a 'equal' result.

Comment: Incidentally I tried putting the view definition as a sub query in the join instead of the view name (sort of simulating the merge algorithm) and I got the correct result, so I'm even more puzzled now. Still, to paraphrase Jerone re MySQL Philosophy, "Never mind the correctness, look at the speed"

Comment: I agree that is weird and I learnt it in hard way :) Glad that it works!

Answer (score 3):

I beg to disagree with other answers. **This is a MySQL defect.** Actually it is bug [#83707](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83707) in MySQL 5.6. It looks it's fixed in MySQL 5.7

This bug is already fixed in MariaDB 5.5.

The internal join strategy such as Nested Loop Join, Merge Join, or Hash Join does not matter. The result should be correct in any case.

I tried the same query in PostgreSQL and Oracle and it works as expected, returning null values on the last three rows.

**Oracle Example**

```
CREATE TABLE person (personID INT); 

INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES (1); 
INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES(2); 
INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES(6);

CREATE TABLE payments (
   payment_personID INT,
   Due INT,
   Paid INT) ;

INSERT INTO payments  (payment_personID, due, paid) VALUES (1, 5, 5);
INSERT INTO payments  (payment_personID, due, paid) VALUES (2, 5, 3);
INSERT INTO payments  (payment_personID, due, paid) VALUES (3, 5, 8);

CREATE VIEW payment_state AS (
SELECT
   payment_personID,
  CASE 
   WHEN COALESCE(paid,0) < COALESCE(due,0) AND due <> 0 THEN 'under' 
   WHEN COALESCE(paid,0) > COALESCE(due,0) THEN 'over' 
   WHEN COALESCE(paid,0) = COALESCE(due,0) THEN 'equal' 
   END AS state 
FROM payments);

SELECT *
FROM
    person
LEFT JOIN 
    payment_state   
ON personID = payment_personID;
```

Result:

```
PERSONID  PAYMENT_PERSONID  STATE
========  ================  =====
       1                 1  equal
       2                 2  under
       3                 3  over
       6            <null>  <null>
       5            <null>  <null>
       4            <null>  <null>
```

Works perfectly!

**PostgreSQL Example**

```
CREATE TABLE person (personID INT); 
INSERT INTO person (personID) VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);

CREATE TABLE payments (
   payment_personID INT,
   Due INT,
   Paid INT) ;

INSERT INTO payments  (payment_personID, due, paid) VALUES
(1, 5, 5), (2, 5, 3), (3, 5, 8);

CREATE VIEW payment_state AS (
SELECT
   payment_personID,
  CASE 
   WHEN COALESCE(paid,0) < COALESCE(due,0) AND due <> 0 THEN 'under' 
   WHEN COALESCE(paid,0) > COALESCE(due,0) THEN 'over' 
   WHEN COALESCE(paid,0) = COALESCE(due,0) THEN 'equal' 
   END AS state 
FROM payments);

SELECT *
FROM
    person
LEFT JOIN 
    payment_state   
ON personID = payment_personID;
```

Result:

```
personid  payment_personid  state
========  ================  =====
       1                 1  equal
       2                 2  under
       3                 3  over
       4            <null>  <null>
       5            <null>  <null>
       6            <null>  <null>
```

Also, works perfectly!

Comment: Well, it appears the [MySQL folks agree](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83707), and it's been fixed in 5.7+.

Comment: but changing IFNULL to COALESCE is also doesn't work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b492af/1

Comment: Ah... OK. So this bug was already reported in November 2016 as bug #83707. The bad news is they don't have any intention yet to fix it. Per ticket comment: "Suggested Fix: a warning should be issued."

Comment: I just tried MariaDB 5.5 (originally a clone of MySQL) and it works perfectly. Those guys already fixed it, but the MySQL guys (Oracle today) are dragging their feet.

Comment: So your solution is basically switching the RDBMS to "PostgreSQL" and replace IFNULL with COALESCE, like how @JeroenMostert suggested in the first comment?

Comment: I thought it looked more like a bug. Unfortunately I have no control over the version of MySQL that I have to interact with on the remote server. I'm stuck with 5.6.12 until they decide to update it. In the meantime I've changed all my views to explicitly use the temptable algorithm, which at least gets round the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal way `LEFT JOIN` works. It appends new columns to the result, then fills them with:

- values pulled from the table being `JOIN`ed if the `JOIN` succeeds,
- `NULL`s if the `JOIN` doesn't match (that includes the fields you joined `ON`)!

Normally there is no distinction between `NULL`s pulled from real tables (where `JOIN` matched) and `NULL`s filled in because the `JOIN` didn't match. The `CASE` + `IFNULL` just look for `NULL`s and swaps them to `0`s (no matter their source). That's why you have results in the *state* column even in unmatched rows.

As a matter of fact, if you want to know if a given `NULL` you are looking at was a result of not matching a `JOIN`, you need to explicitly check this - if all key fields you `JOIN`ed on are `NULL`s, when the `NULL` in this column is a result of a fill-in. If the fields from key are present in this row yet there is still a `NULL` in other column, then it is there because it was pulled from the table you `JOIN`ed.

Comment: @ ensisNoctis quote "NULLs if the JOIN doesn't match". But my point is that I am **not** getting NULLs where the join doesn't match, I'm getting **data**.

Comment: Oh, now I see. You JOIN to a view, then results appear just as the CASE definition was copied to the SELECT (not enough data for a view itself = NULLs, but enough data after JOIN = columns filled). Sorry, I misunderstood your question.